# Which host-url should be provided to Ingress for Traefik in Kubernetes AWS?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, amazon-eks, traefik-ingress

I am trying to set up Treafik in my Kubernetes cluster running on AWS. I am having problems understanding the `host-url` that is used in the `ingress-service`. The tutorial in their page was nice but the think is that running in minikube you have just one node so you are going to map that IP to the Host that you are going to use in Treafik.

I don't know which IP should I map in case of Kubernetes in AWS. The master url? What happens when I have multiple masters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `host-url` is the external IP of the Traefik Load-Balancer in AWS. In minikube there is no external IP so I think they did it this way (to use the minikube IP) for testing.

I suffered a bit to understand the point that when using Traefik (or other Ingress controllers) we have just one Load-Balancer, the one of the Traefik in this case, and the other services will point to this one. Traefik then will redirect the traffic.